# Cancel jQueryUI mouse behavior (resize, drag) with escape key

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-draggable, jquery-resizable

Is it possible to cancel **current** jQueryUI  resizable and draggable interaction with a key press?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's possible. You can check to escape key on the document, and if so disable the draggable feature.

Code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.popup_click').draggable();
 }); 

$(document).keyup(function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 27) {  
      $('.popup_click').draggable( 'disable' ).addClass('disabled');
  }   
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/7L2FY/

### EDIT

To stop drag you can fire a `mouseup`:

```
$(document).keyup(function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 27) {  
      $( '.popup_click' ).trigger( 'mouseup' );
  }   
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/7L2FY/1/

Comment: By canceling interaction I meant aborting in-progress resize/drag.

Comment: I thought about doing it this way but it may cause [problems due to missing event properties](http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/5664#comment:1) and is not supported by jquery devs. Also it does not restore original state.